# Testing ruby with rails, Element not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I get the error:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "user_email"
```

And this is the test code:

```
feature 'User' do
    given!(:user) { User.new(email: 'testuserid@example.com', encrypted_password: 'test') }
    scenario 'opens sign_up page' do
        visit new_user_session_path
        expect(page).to have_content 'unique text on the page'
    end
    scenario 'signs in with invalid email' do
        visit new_user_session_path
            fill_in('user_email',with: 'ssd')
        expect(page).to have_content 'unique text on the page'
    end
end
```

My HTML file consists of this code literally:

```
unique text on the page
<br>
<input type="text" id="user_email">
```

So this proves that the path is correct because my first scenario runs correctly. It is visiting the right page. But still I get this error for second scenario in fill_in.
I have also tried element = page.find("user_email"), it gives same error.
What am I possibly doing wrong?
I have been scratching my head like hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems right. Maybe you are visiting wrong url or you have used `user_email` `id` once more. But you can give a try with alternative syntax like following :

```
find("input[id$='user_email']").set "ssd"
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually the reason for this is that the input isn't actually visible on the page.  You can verify this by doing

```
fill_in('user_email', with: 'ssd', visible: false)
```

If that succeeds in finding the element, then you need to change your test to first perform whatever actions make the field visible before attempting to fill it in.